# When using Office Primary Interop Assembly and calling CustomXMLNode.AppendChildNode(), how can I reference a previously defined XML namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, vsto, office-interop, office-2016

Apparently I am missing something, because I cannot reference a previously defined XML namespace when calling `CustomXMLNode.AppendChildNode()` in Office 2016 or greater:

```
private void AppendChild(Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLNode node)
{
    node.AppendChildNode("nil", "xmlns:xsi", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCustomXMLNodeType.msoCustomXMLNodeAttribute, "true");
}
```

The above call produces:

```
<IndexId xmlns:ns3="xmlns:xsi" ns3:nil="true"></IndexId>
```

Which is not understood by the service I am posting to. The the CustomXMLPart knows about the "xsi" namespace, as is evident in the opening tag of the string returned by `CustomXMLPart.XML`:

```
<ns1:TestData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.rockportsys.com/rockportXML">
```

So apparently, the "NamespaceURI" argument (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.customxmlnode.appendchildnode) is simply taken literally and defined as a new namespace every time. I have tried all of the following to no avail:

```
node.AppendChildNode("nil", "xsi",       Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCustomXMLNodeType.msoCustomXMLNodeAttribute, "true");
node.AppendChildNode("nil", "xsi:",      Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCustomXMLNodeType.msoCustomXMLNodeAttribute, "true");
node.AppendChildNode("nil", ":xsi",      Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCustomXMLNodeType.msoCustomXMLNodeAttribute, "true");
node.AppendChildNode("nil", "xmlns:xsi", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCustomXMLNodeType.msoCustomXMLNodeAttribute, "true");
```

All of the above calls produce the equivalent of the following with `<NamespaceURI_arg>` replaced by the string passed in as the second argument above:

```
<IndexId xmlns:ns3="<NamespaceURI_arg>" ns3:nil="true"></IndexId>
```

None of which work with the consuming service. How the heck are we supposed to reference a previously-defined namespace when adding a child element? What is the magic incantation?

The only way I have been able to get it working is with:

```
node.AppendChildNode("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCustomXMLNodeType.msoCustomXMLNodeAttribute, "true");
```

Which produces the unnecessarily verbose:

```
<IndexId xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns0:nil="true"></IndexId>
```

Comment: Could you please edit into your question a bit of *simple*, sample XML for the Custom XML Part so that we have something to test with? Note that VBA will *not* use the pre-defined namespace aliases in existing XML. It assigns its own (ns-prefix), so using the namespace manager functionality is usually necessary.